# inserting a , in a number thats greater than 999

Tags: .net, vb.net

im working on a project that is calculating the total population for given countries and its in the hundreds of thousands.  And i need to output the population with the ,'s in the appropriate places.
Ex.  population 123456789
i need to output it in a listbox as
123,456,789

so im looking for a converter function or something built in that takes my value 
Dim population as int

and adds it appropriately

```
    Lbxdata.Items.Add("----------------------------")

    Lbxdata.Items.Add(("Total Countries Selected " & countrycount))

    Lbxdata.Items.Add(("Total Population Selected " & (totalPopulation))

    Lbxdata.Items.Add("----------------------------")
```

is what i have atm.

Comment: i'd convert integer to string first, then insert comma at appropriate location.  `mid(string, 4,7)` for example lets you grab 4th to 7th char from the string

Comment: @yosukesabai That's not the recommended solution in .net.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: i guess it is bad answer in 'vb' as well.  i read the title and wrote answer without thinking too much, interpreted it too literally...  or is there particular reason beside formatting methods are available?

Comment: I only talked about .net because I have no clue what formatting methods are available in VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to format the lines:

```
Lbxdata.Items.Add(String.Format("Total Countries Selected {0:N0}", countrycount))

Lbxdata.Items.Add(String.Format("Total Population Selected {0:N0}", totalPopulation))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should format your number as

```
value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

So your code could be:

```
Lbxdata.Items.Add("Total Countries Selected " & _
    countrycount.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
Lbxdata.Items.Add("Total Population Selected " & _
    totalPopulation.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

See docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Y4297)

Comment: I'd say this is a case for _not_ using invariant culture. What does 123,031 mean? that depends on which side of the atlantic ocean you live. Not taking that into account is IMO an error

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your integer to a string, or a character array and simply insert a comma every three digits working from Strin.lenght()-1 backwards, then set the text atribute of the view using this string.

Or convert to string and use String.Format("###,###");